# In boolean algebra, why is a+a'b = a+b?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Looking at the truth table, they're equivalent:

```
A   B      (A+B)  (A+A'B)
-------------------------------
1   1       1       1
1   0       1       1
0   1       1       1
0   0       0       0
```

But what manipulation can one do using basic identifies and laws to show that they're the same?

Comment: By `A'` you mean *not A*? I personally never used nor seen used that notation. I think $\overline{A}$ and $\lnot A$ are much more used around the world (or at least in the material I have seen).

Comment: @Bakuriu it's a notation that's used more in computer science, out of the necessity of not being able to do overbar in ASCII. See: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse370/99sp/lectures/02-Comb/sld008.htm

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note with the laws of Boolean algebra, "addition" distributes over "multiplication" (just as multiplication would normally distribute over addition).  Thus, we have
$$
a + (a'\cdot b) = (a+a')\cdot (a+b) = 1(a+b) = a+b
$$

Comment: Thanks. It's easy to forget that multiplication distribute over addition in boolean algebra.

Comment: You mean the other way.

Comment: Huh, I knew the law but it hadn't sunk in for me that it's really addition distributing over multiplication. +1 for phrasing it that way!

Comment: @Leif what is it that you think I mean?

Comment: I meant OP means addition distributes over multiplication - that that's the hard to forget part.

Answer (score 21):

$A+A'B=A(1+B)+A'B=A+AB+A'B=A+(A+A')B=A+B$